# Inherit Data Annotation StringLengthAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, custom-attributes

I want to create a custom attribute by inheriting the `StringLengthAttribute`. The reason for doing this is because I need to use a dynamic error message. The default ErrorMessage only support a constant message. It's working when I using the default validation without a constant message.

```
public class CustomerProfile
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Original Error Message")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

But when I use code below to create custom the message, It's showing as a pop up alert box instead of show the validation message above the textbox.

```
public class CustomerProfile
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    //[StringLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Original Error Message")]
    [MaxNameLengthAttributes(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class MaxNameLengthAttributes : StringLengthAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxWords;

    public MaxNameLengthAttributes(int maxWords) : base(maxWords)
    {
        _maxWords = maxWords;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult("Name required");

        var textValue = value.ToString();

        if (textValue.Length <= _maxWords)
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        var errorMessage = string.Format("max length is {0}",_maxWords);

        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I create a custom message by inheriting the default attribute and display the validation message above the textbox instead of popup alert box?

**Remarks:**

If inherit StringLength attribute, it's suppose working fine without using IClientValidatable. And the message suppose won't become popup alert, any missing part?

Comment: http://dotnetmentors.com/mvc/how-to-do-custom-validation-using-validationattribute-of-aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, It's not dynamic error message, please refer my code. Thanks

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the example provide not inherit the StringLength attribute, I was thinking if straight using that attribute, I no need to create IClientValidatable anymore.

Comment: You should not inherit from `StringLengthAttribute` to do what you want - you should inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and implement `IClientValidatable`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, actually my length validation is same as StringLengthAttribute, just want to dynamic the message, why cannot inherit it?

Comment: I assumed that `_maxWords` was used for counting words rather that characters, which is what you are doing, so what is the point of your attribute. Just use the `[StringLength(ErrorMessage = "max length is {1}")]` attribute. And as a side note, a `ValidationAttribute` has one responsibility so your `if (value == null) { return new ValidationResult("Name required"); }` block is wrong - you handle that with a `[Required]` attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, [StringLength(ErrorMessage = "max length is {1}")] is solved my issue, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
 [Remote("MaxNameLengthAttributes", "ControllerName", AdditionalFields = "Id", HttpMethod = "POST", 
      ErrorMessage = "max length is 10")]
 public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Then you can add a method in your controller like that

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MaxNameLengthAttributes(string Name, long? id)
    {
       if(Name.Length<10)
         return Json(false);
       else 
          return Json(true);
    }
```

May be this will help for you.

Comment: Please check this Link.you can solve your displaying custom message.                       
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ff398048(v=vs.100).aspx